# Build a hardware clone or emulator of Apple II?

Tags: apple-ii, emulation, clone, diy-computing

These days we are constantly seeing low-cost boards that have huge power (raspberry pi, various arduino-like microcontrollers.)

I am hoping I could make, or get, a clone or emulation of an Apple II that was "stand alone" in a piece of hardware... instead of running within a larger PC.

Can you tell me the options in doing such a thing?

- I know that one option is Linapple or Linapple-Pi.   Is that pretty much the main option? -- for example https://www.reddit.com/r/apple2/comments/8uxiwr/35_apple_powered_by_linapple_and_raspberry_pi/
- No chance that someone has (maybe illegally) taken the whole Apple II, placed it onto chips in a small board, and sells that?

Comment: You may want to look at something like this too: https://hackaday.com/2017/10/10/apple-ii-fpga/

Comment: Can you suggest what facilities it's important (or not important) the clone should have and whether you prefer these to be the original interfaces or emulated? For example, should you be able to attach an original Apple II disk drive to it and use that, or should there be only an emulated drive, or both, or (unlikely I know) no drive at all? The same goes for video output (and the 80 column card), and the langauge, printer and serial cards, just off the top of my head.

Comment: Wow.  well, to me personally, no need at all to run an old drive -- I'd be happy to just load disk image files. ... and yeah, for 40/80 columns, well, I'm weird and I guess I'd like an apple II+ so 40 columns would be fine, but hey, if there was a configuration to turn on a super correct standard 80 column display, then hey, that's fair.  ** I have to admit that running a good strong emulator on a Raspberry Pi may indeed be the best way for what I'd like. I'm a fan of RetroPie... so... something along those lines... I guess I should learn more about LinApple. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: If you're going with Linapple for emulation, this is the fork that's maintained and is more likely to work: https://github.com/linappleii/linapple . Linapple-Pi(e) has problems

Answer (score 13):

There's [a full clone of a revision 0 Apple II motherboard](http://www.willegal.net/appleii/appleii-recreation.htm) made by one avid retrocomputing enthusiast.

He no longer has kits for sale, but the board Gerber files are available.  Order some boards from a PCB manufacturer, source the components, and you'll have everything to build your own complete Apple II mainboard.

Comment: cool. deep down I keep hoping that on AliExpress I'll find some company that has a little apple II clone with HDMI and SD ram lots... beige plastic enclosure, maybe 6 inches across :)

Comment: that is a cool site. made me wish I was about 5 steps more capable than I am...

Comment: The boards and some of the chips are currently sold here: https://www.reactivemicro.com/product/apple-ii-rev-0/

Comment: Looks like they sell them complete and tested, too: https://www.reactivemicro.com/product/apple-ii-plus-rev-7-rfi-motherboard/ — and not just revision 0.

Answer (score 7):

The [MiSTer project](https://github.com/MiSTer-devel/Main_MiSTer/wiki) is an Open Source effort to create clone consoles/computers on the [Terasic DE10-nano](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=167&No=1046) FPGA dev kit

They have an [Apple II+ core](https://github.com/MiSTer-devel/Apple-II_MiSTer) available and the MiSTer can be configured to boot directly into it

Comment: This is exciting. A question ... is the apple II+ core pretty solid/robust or does it fail for various uses? For an example, I always thought that someday I would go learn 6502 assembly. Could I on this? Also, would it run common Apple II disk images that I download from various sources?  Thanks! I will keep reading.

Comment: The answer is yes to both. Some of the CPU implementations in MiSTer are “cycle-accurate” (where even timing is identical to the original) and some are functionally accurate - but all of them are accurate enough to learn and run assembly on. For Apple II disk images just drop the *.nib files onto the SD card and you’re good to go

Comment: PS the MOS 6502 used by the Apple II was very popular - found in the Atari 2600, C64, NES and many more. I think it’s likely the implementation is very accurate/good